# How to use package restore with packages containing only tools?

Tags: .net, mercurial, nuget

I use Nuget with [enabled Package Restore feature](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages). Thus `/packages` folder is in ignore list (`.hgignore` since I use mercurial). That works fine on my CI server (Teamcity).

To be able to run xUnit tests I added [xunit.runners](http://nuget.org/packages/xunit.runners) package. However this package contains only `tools` folder and after it has been added no any changes were detected by mercurial (nothing new to commit). Seems like only `/packages` folder got updated.

How to enable package restore for such packages (containing only `tools`)?

For now the only solution I found is using regexp syntax in `.hgignore`:

```
syntax: regexp
packages/(?!xunit.runner).*
```

But in this case it just saves all package content in source control.

Comment: Include xunit.runner to your tests project. So when you will build tests it automatically restore runner.

Comment: btw, issue already recorded for nuget - http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1880?ProjectName=nuget you can vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try manually add package xunit.runners to your packages.config. This will resolve runner when you will first build your tests or solution.

Comment: Thx, that is better than including part of packages folders to commit. Will wait until nuget gets updated.